# making the navbar items in the menu to enlarge on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

so this js code is responsible for highlighting menu on scroll but it doesnt work.
i dont know what the problem is, also another issue is that when i try to console.log(pageXOffset) or console.log(sectionLeft) they both dont log any value to the console and nothing happens when i scroll, its not a part of the actual code but i just wanted to get the values and see how they change on scroll.

```
         <script>
            const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
            const navLi = document.getElementsByClassName('navbarItem');
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function (){
                changeOnScroll()
            });
            function changeOnScroll(){
                let currentx=""
                console.log(pageXOffset)
                for( i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
                    const sectionLeft = sections[i].offsetLeft;
                    console.log(sectionLeft)
                    const sectionWidth = sections[i].clientWidth;
                    if( pageXOffset >= sections[i].offsetLeft ){
                        currentx = sections[i].getAttribute('id');
                    }
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++){
                    navbarItem[i].classList.remove('active');
                    if(currentx = sections[i]){
                        navbarItem[i].classList.add('active')
                    }
                }
            }     
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav id="navbar">
                <ul id="navbarlist">
                    <li class="navbarItem home"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbarItem about"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li class="navbarItem products"><a href="#products">products</a></li>
                    <li class="navbarItem services"><a href="#services">services</a></li>
                    <li class="navbarItem contactus"><a href="#contactus">contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="outer-wrapper">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">
                    <section class="sections" id="home">
                    </section>
                    <section class="sections" id="about">
                    </section>
                    <section class="sections" id="products">
                    </section>
                    <section class="sections" id="services">
                    </section>
                    <section class="sections" id="contactus">
                    </section>
```

and this is my css:

```
#navbar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    left: calc(50vw - 25vw);

}
#navbarlist{
    top: 50px;
    left: 25vw;
    width: 50vw;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbarItem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.navbarItem:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.current{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: aqua;
}
.currentx{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: aqua;
}
.active{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: aqua;
}
.sections{
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: You may like to investigate IntersectionObserver to prevent you having to sense every scroll change in JS yourself.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you! i didnt know about that, will definitely look into it.